# how to make our activity page open from another application?

Tags: java, android

I am new in android development, I want to build a music player but the problem in front of me is how do i make my app open from gallery.
For example,
if we want to open any music file then we select it, the the android mobile ask which player do we want to use.

so how can I add my app in that option.

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your app to be in the list for opening an audio file, you need to tell the system your app can open those files. You can do that by adding something like the following to your `activity` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content"/>
    <data android:scheme="file"/>
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
</intent-filter>
```

[`Intent filters`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) are part of the core principles in Android development. You should try to get some knowledge on these basic topics before getting started.

Answer (score 0):

It helps you

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i am sorry but i am completely new in android development please if you can be specific and explain how it works.

Comment: when you click song, you just make to call above code. YOUR_SONG_URI is your song url. then it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can open activity not app at self just simply add action intent filter in mainfest like this

```
<activity class=".foo" android:label="@string/title_notes_list">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.me.love" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

other app code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.me.love");
startActivity(intent);
```

however if you want to tell android system that your activity can handle some actions like share or send data you just have to add "send" action to your activity in mainfest like so :

```
<activity class=".boo" android:label="@string/title_notes_list">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
         </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

so now when ever user click share button android system will check all activitys that have action string "android.intent.action.SEND" then give the user list of activitys that have `send` action and if you did added same action as `boo` activity dose to your activity then it will be one of chooses in the list.